# How does Sundering Titan handle snow lands?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My doubt is about [Sundering Titan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSundering%20Titan%5d); what happens when it enters and leaves the battlefield if there are snow lands in play? Does it destroy basic lands and snow basic lands and how much of each of them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it can destroy both snow-covered basic lands and non-snow-covered basic lands. It's up to Sundering Titan's controller; he or she must choose one land of each basic type (Plains, Island, Swamp, Mountain, Forest) (provided such a land is present on the battlefield). Snow-covered lands have basic land types, so the Titan's controller can choose them as well, but he/she can't destroy e.g. a Mountain and a Snow-covered Mountain during the same effect.

Comment: It doesn't even have to be a basic land, just to contain a basic type. A gate for example, which is a nonbasic land, can be picked twice. You pick basic landtypes, not necessarily basic lands.

Comment: @Mast, you are claiming gates can be destroyed by Sundering Titan.  That is not the case.  They don't have any basic land types.  Tropical Island is an example of a non-basic land, that has basic land types.

Comment: @Mast Gates do not have basic land types, and therefore cannot be chosen for Sundering Titan

Comment: @Hackworth If a guild gate has both plains and island as type (Azorius gate), those are both basic land types and it should be able to be destroyed, no?

Comment: The fact that it produces W and U doesn't mean it has Plains or Island as subtypes...

Comment: @Mast No, gates such as Azorius Guildgate have only the gate subtype. Just because it produces blue and white mana doesnt mean it has the island and/or plains type. What matters is the type line, and for gates it says "Land - Gate". Land is the type, Gate is the only subtype. Sundering Titan can choose lands that have the Plains, Island, Swamp, Mountain, and/or Forest subtype.

Answer (score 13):

"Snow" is a supertype.  If you look at [Snow-Covered Plains](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSnow-Covered%20Plains%5d) you will see that it's types are "Snow Basic Land - Plains".  Which means that it counts as a basic land and a plains.

So in the case of Sundering Titan, if there was both a regular Plains card and a Snow Covered Plains out, you could only choose one of them to destroy.

Relevant rules:
From the comprehensive rules glossary

> Basic Land Type There are five "basic land types": Plains, Island,
>   Swamp, Mountain, and Forest. Each one has a mana ability associated
>   with it. See rule 305, "Lands."

And

> 205.4c Any land with the supertype "basic" is a basic land. Any land that doesn't have this supertype is a nonbasic land, even if it has a
>   basic land type.: Cards printed in sets prior to the Eighth Edition
>   core set didn't use the word "basic" to indicate a basic land. Cards
>   from those sets with the following names are basic lands and have
>   received errata in the Oracle card reference accordingly: Forest,
>   Island, Mountain, Plains, Swamp, Snow-Covered Forest, Snow-Covered
>   Island, Snow-Covered Mountain, Snow-Covered Plains, and Snow-Covered
>   Swamp.

And from the rulings on Snow Covered Plains:

> “Snow” has no particular meaning or rules associated with it.

Also (emphasis mine)

> Since this is a **basic land**, you may have any number of it in a
>   Constructed deck in any format in which the *Masters Edition II* set,
>   the *Coldsnap* set, or the *Ice Age* set is legal.

Comment: Your link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

Sundering Titan can destroy snow lands because cares about lands having a basic land type (Forest, Plains, Island, Swamp, Mountain), not about those lands having the name "Forest", "Plains", etc.

For each land type (Forest, Plains, Island, Swamp, Mountain), you get to choose a land that has that type to destroy.  Here are some examples of lands that can be chosen as a forest by Sundering Titan:

- [Forest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bForest%5d)
- [Snow-Covered Forest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSnow-Covered%20Forest%5d)
- [Temple Garden](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTemple%20Garden%5d)
- [Sapseep Forest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSapseep%20Forest%5d)
- [Murmuring Bosk](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMurmuring%20Bosk%5d)
- [Dryad Arbor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDryad%20Arbor%5d)
- Any saproling creature if [Life and Limb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLife%20and%20Limb%5d) is in play